# Cannot add free space into macOS partition because "the disk for one of the specified operations could not be found"

Tags: macos, mac, partition

How can I merge free space into the active partition "Macintosh HD"?

```
ADMINs-Mac:~ admin$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *107.4 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            42.6 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

[image: Disk Utility showing partition pie chart]

I have tried the following:

[image: Remove free space, resize Macintosh HD]
[image: Boot drive repartitioning warning]
[image: Error message]

> An internal error has occurred and he disk for one of the specified operations could not be found. This may be a temporary issue, try again.

Answer (score 1):

Michael's command may solve the question of how to delete free partion.

[Can't resize partition on VMWare Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/331175/cant-rezize-partition-on-vmware-mac/337347)

Answer (score 0):

In the box marked "Size" enter 107.37 or drag the resize control (I'm guessing that's the white dot on the outside of the circle), then click Apply.

Comment: 2nd operation of resizing failed